# np.argmax doesn't return integer

Tags: python, numpy, one-hot-encoding

I have some onehot encoded data called testoutput, which has shape (1000,14).

I want to decode it, so following some advice I found online I used the following code:

```
# go from onehot encoding to integer
def decode(datum):
    return np.argmax(datum)

predictedhits=np.empty((1000))
for i in range(testoutput.shape[0]):
    datum = testoutput[i]
    predictedhits[i] = decode(datum)
    print('Event',i,'predicted number of hits: %s' % predictedhits[i])
```

The problem is that I wanted and expected np.argmax to output an integer, but instead it outputs  a numpy.float64.
Please can someone tell me why this happens and what do do about it? Simply doing predictedhits[i] = int(decode(datum)) doesn't change anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misdiagnosed the problem. `numpy.argmax` is not returning an instance of `numpy.float64`. Rather, `predictedhits` has float64 dtype. Storing any value into that array stores it as a 64-bit float, and retrieving `predictedhits[i]` from the array produces a `numpy.float64` object.

Instead of iterating over rows of `testoutput` one at a time and storing values into an empty array one by one, just call `argmax` along the axis you want:

```
predictedhits = np.argmax(testoutput, axis=1)
```

This saves code, saves runtime, and produces an array of the proper dtype.

Comment: This is great, now when I `print()` the values of `predictedhits[i]` it prints integers, however when I investigate `type(predictedhits[0])` it stilles gives me `numpy.float64`, and when I do `np.savetxt` it gives me floats. Can you help me with this too?

Comment: @BethLong: You did something else weird somewhere we can't see.

Comment: The code for the savetxt is here:
`np.savetxt("/content/drive/My Drive/PVetoMCPredictionThousandHits.txt",predictedhits,delimiter="\n")`
There's no other code between the line you gave me and this...

Comment: Please clarify further. testoutput is a dataframe? if so then testoutput[1] should raise an Key Error. Isnt it? Correct me please

Comment: @NiteshJindal no, testoutput is a numpy.ndarray